# How to join two table values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables namely States & Districts . Common column in those table is StateID.

I want to display state name under that district names in that state

Result format should be like below:

**Tamilnadu**

Chennai

Coimbatore

**Karnataka**

Bangalore

Mysore
.

.

.

Pls tel me how to join the tables to get the above results using sql query.

Comment: This is very basic stuff. What are the tables columns? Also, have you tried anything?

Comment: @Acdcjunior: Thanks for your reply my table contains below columns  States table: stateid , Satatename      city table : cityid,cityname, stateid

Comment: @kannan Cities or Districts? Make your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT sc.name 
FROM
       states AS s2 
LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT s.statename AS name, 
               s.stateid 
          FROM   states s 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT c.cityname AS name, 
              c.stateid 
          FROM   city c) AS sc 
ON sc.stateid = s2.stateid
```

**Output:**

> **Tamilnadu**
>   Chennai
>   Coimbatore
>   **Karnataka**
>   Bangalore
>   Mysore

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
select StateID, StateName, 0 Sort from States
union all
select StateID, DistrictName, 1 Sort From Districts
order by StateID, Sort
```

Comment: i got below error message
'group_concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT StateName, group_concat(DistrictName)
  FROM Districts d JOIN States s
    ON d.StateID = s.StateID
group by StateName
ORDER BY StateName, DistrictName
```

Comment: There is no GROUP_CONCAT function in SQL Server

Comment: sorry for that, leaving conservation as you marked thread as solved.